# how to set mail category color in exchange 2010 using java

Tags: java, email, set, exchange-server, categories

How to set category mail color on exchange 2010 using java? i didn't find any methods in javax.mail which I'm using.
I can read message, change flag seen but can't set catgory color

Answer (score 0):

The category comes from the Keyword header in Mime https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee159893(v=exchg.80).aspx so you just need to set the underlying RFC Keywords header https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#page-12 in the message